# Azure AKS clusters API AuthenticationFailed error

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-aks

I need programically get user AKS clusters , but

i have problem when execute this request 
[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters?api-version=2018-03-31](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/75a3ba1b-6e0b-4d2a-8c8c-0f1a967e9711/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters?api-version=2018-03-31)

Headers : 
Authorization: bearer {JWT}

I get

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationFailed",
        "message": "Authentication failed."
    }
}
```

How i retrieve this JWT token

I use this flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#web-application-to-web-api for implementation

1. I use it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code for get code
2. After i try retrieve access token
   [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant-id%7D/oauth2/token)
   Headers :

grant_type : authorization_code 
client_id : {myapp-id} 
code : {Retrieve from step 1} 
client_secret : {myapp-key} 
resource : https://graph.microsoft.com

And in result i has JWT token with payload

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/ee3f07b0-0b4f-4929-acb0-643894a174fa/",
  "iat": 1533214682,
  "nbf": 1533214682,
  "exp": 1533218582,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ],
  "app_displayname": "SinglePageApp-jQuery-DotNet",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "ipaddr": "193.243.159.58",
  "name": "Pasha Kostohrys",
  "platf": "3",
  "puid": "1003BFFDAC20BE5D",
  "scp": "Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All Member.Read.Hidden User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "wids": [
    "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audience of the bearer token you retrieved is `https://graph.microsoft.com/`, but the audience of the API you requested is `https://management.core.windows.net/`.

I think you should use `resource : https://management.core.windows.net/` to get the bearer token, it will work.

Comment: Yes.I had incorrect permission and incorrect resource. So currently it works. Thanks

Comment: havent enought reputation :(
Currently has problem with multi-tenant , i enable it but users from other organizations havent ability login :(